# Replacing fragments in one activity

Tags: android, xamarin

I am able to add a fragment to my fragmentlayout, but when I'm trying to replace the fragment with a new one the screen is blank. I can add a new fragment but then it's not scrollable. I'm also not able not remove a fragment.
Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? I red a lot about it and I feel like I have tried everything..

The framelayout is defined static:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>'
```

And this is the method for switching fragments:
        void TabOnTabSelected (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs tabEventArgs)
        {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = (ActionBar.Tab)sender;

```
    var fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();

    switch (tab.Text) {
    case "vandaag":
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.Remove (FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag ("gister"));
        }
        if (fragmentToday == null) {
            fragmentToday = WZWVDataOverview.NewInstance (DateTime.Now.AddDays (0).ToString ("d-M-yyyy"));
        }
        fragmentTransaction.Add (Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragmentToday, "vandaag");
        currentFragment = fragmentToday;
        break;
    case "gister":
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.Remove (currentFragment);
        }

        if (fragmentYesterday == null) {
            fragmentYesterday = WZWVDataOverview.NewInstance (DateTime.Now.AddDays (-1).ToString ("d-M-yyyy"));
        }
        currentFragment = fragmentYesterday;
        fragmentTransaction.Add (Resource.Id.fragment_container, currentFragment, "gister");

        break;

    case "morgen":
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.Remove (currentFragment);
        }
        if (fragmentTomorrow == null) {
            fragmentTomorrow = WZWVDataOverview.NewInstance (DateTime.Now.AddDays (+1).ToString ("d-M-yyyy"));
        }
        fragmentTransaction.Add (Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragmentTomorrow);
        currentFragment = fragmentTomorrow;
        break;
    }

    fragmentTransaction.Commit ();
}
```

XML of the framelayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the .replace method. If you do not wish to be able to move back to the previous fragment than you can remove addToBackStack().

This may need to be altered slightly to fit your application.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
Fragment mFragment = new DetailFragment();
mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment).addToBackStack("DETAILFRAGMENT").commit();
```

**POSSIBLE SECOND SOLUTION:**

Check to see how your Fragment layout XML is. Possibly try using a FrameLayout as the parent.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.modup.fragment.DetailFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I already tried replace since it the most natural solution but it's somehow not working. I end up with a blank screen.

Comment: Can you post the XML layout of a Fragment that you are having issues with? I posted a potential second solution.

Comment: I added the frame layout, going to try your second solution

Comment: I just found a mistake in my code, it didn't had anything to do with replacing or adding new fragments. I OnCreateView from my fragment I initialized only my listview if the adapter was null, changing this line of code resolved my issue. I now can use replace and everything is fine. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have open fragments from navigation view as items are selected from it.(I have use DataBinding Concept)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.k15.projectkhyatisalesapp.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#ef6c00"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/activity_main_frame_layout"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:menu="@menu/listnavigation" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<layout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//Declaration of Variables
private ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;        //for binding values in xml
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawableToogle;      //This class provides a handy way to tie together the functionality of DrawerLayout and the framework ActionBar to implement the recommended design for navigation drawers.
private Fragment fragment;
private Class fragmentClass = null;     //pointing to class of fragment

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    setSupportActionBar(mainBinding.toolbar);   //o designate a Toolbar as the action bar for an Activity
    setUpDrawer(mainBinding.activityMainNavigation);    //for select items in navigationView

    mDrawableToogle = setupToogle();
    mainBinding.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawableToogle);
}


//private method to set navigationView
private void setUpDrawer(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            try {
                selectItem(item);   //call when item is selected from navigationView
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

//items are selected from navigationView
public void selectItem(MenuItem menuItem) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Home:
            fragmentClass = Home.class;
            break;
        case R.id.Product:
            fragmentClass = Product.class;
            break;
        case R.id.Media:
            fragmentClass = Media.class;
            break;
    }

    assert fragmentClass != null;
    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(mainBinding.activityMainFrameLayout.getId(), fragment).commit(); //change the fragment
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    menuItem.setCheckable(true);  //for set selected item
    mainBinding.drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawableToogle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawableToogle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupToogle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mainBinding.drawerLayout, mainBinding.toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
}
```

menu/listnavigation.xml is attached to navigation view I contains items of navigation view.

In my code as items are selected from navigation view accordingly fragment is replaced. Here Home, Product, Media are my fragment, you can create any fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `fragmentTransaction.replace()` instead of `fragmentTransaction.add()` and comment out code for removing fragments. When you replace the fragment - it gets removed. Also - remember to call: `fragmentTransaction.commit()` when you are done with replacing fragments.